# samba question: share = user

Tags: 13.04, windows, permissions, samba

- I am running Ubuntu 13.04 and Windows XP.
- I am a samba newbie but was able to set this up on Ubuntu following the instructions posted here https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html
- My question is that although I can copy a word document to the share from linux, when I edit it in Word on Windows I cannot save and overwrite the file. It says the file is read only.
- I have to save a copy and then do a move of the file on the Linux system.
- I tried changing the perms of the file to 777 on the linux side but this didn't fix it so I am thinking it is a perms at the user level.
- Does anyone know off the top of their head? I currently have security = user in my smb.conf file.
- When copying a file from linux to the share it has my user name on it. When creating a file from windows to the share it has  nobody nogroup on the file.
- The good news is both linux and windows see the same files and I can open all the files put on the share in windows I just can't overwrite them with edits ( word 2007 files specifically ).
- Any help on the setting to fix this is appreciated.

samba details

```
[share]
   comment = Ubuntu File Share
   path = /srv/samba/share
   browseable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 0775

permissions of all the directories for /srv/samba/share

bjackfly@BigJackFly:~$ ls -ltr | grep srv
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Sep 25 14:05 srv

bjackfly@BigJackFly:~$ ls -ltr /srv/ | grep samba
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep 25 14:05 samba

bjackfly@BigJackFly:~$ ls -ltr /srv/samba/ | grep share
drwxrwxrwx 2 nobody nogroup 4096 Sep 25 17:25 share
```

Comment: Could you post at least the `[YourShareName]` portion of your smb.conf file and also the output of `ls -la /srv/samba/YourShareName`? There's a good chance that your `create mask = 0755` line is wrong or missing or that your skipped the `chown` step.

Comment: I added the details requested. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make sure that files in the share had nobody.nogroup

```
sudo chown nobody.nogroup  file.docx
```